# Add and remove Node in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 Node Elasticsearch cluster, all three nodes are data and master. I have some question regarding upgrade and downgrade our Elasticsearch cluster

1. What is the correct way to add and remove node (I have gone through
   many tutorials but not getting accurate steps)?
2. Do I need to update config in each cluster when I am going to add or remove node, and also do I need to restart all the Elasticsearch?
3. Is it fine to have all three node with master and node?

Here is my sample Elasticsearch config, I have enabled master check true on single node. Is this good or need some changes

```
cluster.name: test-cluster
node.name: test-node-1
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 10.0.1.11 
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.0.1.11", "10.0.1.12", "10.0.1.13"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.0.1.11"]
node.master: true

cluster.name: test-cluster
node.name: test-node-2
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 10.0.1.12 
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.0.1.11", "10.0.1.12", "10.0.1.13"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.0.1.11"]

cluster.name: test-cluster
node.name: test-node-3
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 10.0.1.13
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.0.1.11", "10.0.1.12", "10.0.1.13"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.0.1.11"]
```

Comment: Can you tell, from which version you are upgrading to which version?

Comment: upgrade and downgrade means increase or decrease nodes